duplicating values to the same column different time
I'm using excel. I have an array of data that I need to duplicate to the same column in different amount of times. the array of data can change in length, in the example picture I put 3 lines but it is much larger and can change in length. the QTY next to the data is the amount of time each line in the data column needs to be duplicated


Welcome to Superuser. Can you share with us what you've tried so far and the research that you've done trying to solve this?

What work have you done so far?

=tocol(ifs(sequence(,max(B2:B4))<=B2:B4,A2:A4),2) like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74571541/12634230

Many ways to do, why learn only one way, here are multiple alternative ways : Here

you are amazing! this work. I never though of using max in the sequence equation. I tried a lot of things like: =LET(arr,A2:A4,TOCOL(EXPAND(arr,VLOOKUP(arr,$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)))) and  =LET(arr,A2:A4,TOCOL(IFERROR(EXPAND(arr,,VLOOKUP(arr,$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)),arr))) etc. but nothing work. thanks a lot
